# Subclass a list and modify its append method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a custom list. Here is the class code I currently have:

```
class Path(list):
    """
    A path from the voltage source to ground.
    The path will be the components involved, and not the
    connections.
    """
    def append(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, Component):
            raise RuntimeError("Only components can be added.")
        elif value in self.path: # <-- how to check if it's in the current list?
            pass
        else:
            super().__append__(value)
```

`super().__append__(value)` is not a valid method to call. What would be a proper way to overwrite the list's append method in this custom list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append` isn't a special method (as you noticed when you defined your own), it doesn't have dunders (`__`) on either side. `super().append(value)` is the call to make to call `list`'s identically named method.

To your other comment, test `elif value in self:`; you *are* a `list`, you don't *have* an attribute named `path` containing a `list`  (or you shouldn't), so you use `self` like one.

Comment: thank you, that worked as was the answer I was looking for. Cheers